# How to style a TextBox ScrollBar with my own images?

Tags: c#, wpf

I was wondering if it is possible to insert my own bitmaps for scrollbar styling. I would like to to use an image for up/down arrows, background and scroller. This is what I have to start with, but I just don't know how to access these mentioned properties:

```
  <TextBox Name="SlideNotes" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Grid.Row="27" Grid.Column="11" Grid.ColumnSpan="46" Grid.RowSpan="5">
                <TextBox.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>

                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Resources>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: There's actually an `ImageBrush` class that you can use to set an image to any property that uses Brushes (`Background`, `Foreground`, `BorderBrush`, `Fill`, etc.)

Comment: @ almulo Can you please provide a sample code?

Comment: I could, but the MSDN is gonna make it a lot better than me ;) 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749021(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @ almulo Thank you. But how to apply this to the background of my scrollbar which is a textbox resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ImageBrush` to set an image to any property that uses Brushes (`Background`, `Foreground`, `BorderBrush`, `Fill`, etc.).

In your case, you'd use it like this:

```
<TextBox Name="SlideNotes" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Grid.Row="27" Grid.Column="11" Grid.ColumnSpan="46" Grid.RowSpan="5">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="yourimage.jpg" Stretch="Fill" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

`ImageBrush` (and all other Brushes that inherit from `TileBrush`) has a set of properties that control how the image is shown. I've used `Stretch="Fill"` in my sample, which will make the image stretch to fill all the space available, but you could want it to behave differently.

For instance, this...

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="yourimage.jpg" Stretch="None" TileMode="FlipXY" />
```

Will make your image repeat, with tiles alternatively flipped horizontally and/or vertically.

Toy around with `Stretch` and `TileMode` (or even `ViewPort`, `ViewPortUnit`, `Viewbox` and `ViewboxUnit`, if you feel brave enough) to get the effect you want.

**EDIT** - As with `RepeatButton`, the default `ScrollBar` template seems to pretty much ignore the `Background` property, most of the time, as well as other properties you could use for customization... This means you'll probably have to override the whole template to customize it to your liking.

Here's one `ScrollBar` template sample: [ScrollBar Styles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173(v=vs.100).aspx)

And here's another for the `RepeatButton`:  [RepeatButton Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468219(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much. I copy-pasted the entire template, but the code complains about static resources, for example: Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}". Isimply removed all those lines, but then main app crashes

Comment: and if you could please just point out where in the template I should add the lines for image brush.

Comment: If you check the last part of the MSDN pages I linked, there's a list of the Resources you need for the templates to work. And in order to change the `ScrollBar` background, I'd say that the best part to look for is the `<Track x:Name="PART_Track" ...>` element inside the template (the `Track` is what connects the two `RepeatButton` and where the `Thumb` travels up and down)

Comment: Actually, the background for scrollbar worked with simple code that you provided, but the Thumb and RepeatButton require something more complex. Where exactly would I add all those resources for template to work?

Comment: In any Resource dictionary, as long as they're defined BEFORE the actual Style or Template uses them :P `StaticResource` references need that the referenced resource is defined in XAML beforehand.

Comment: got it lol, thanks! so, for repeat buttons, where should I look in order to insert the bitmap? As I said, the background for scrollbar worked. Sorry if I ask too much :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're after a `ControlTemplate`. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37366/Styling-A-ScrollViewer-Scrollbar-In-WPF) for a nice tutorial on how to style one.

To avoid having to style the *entire* `ScrollViewer`, you can instead style **only** the `RepeatButton` element, this will make things much easier to work with.

```
<Style TargetType="RepeatButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            ...
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You may need to define this style in the `Window` Resources, instead of the `TextBox` resources due to the scope.

See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296241(v=vs.95).aspx) for `RepeatButton` styles and templates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried just to simply change the foreground and background color of "RepeatButton" but nothing happened. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: The `RepeatButton` template is not too customization-friendly, you'll probably have to override the whole template... Look around for "RepeatButton ControlTemplate" to find the default template, copy it, and modify it as you see fit. For instance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468219(v=vs.100).aspx